# How to stop http websites and links from being entered into a <textarea> dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, textarea

Would it be possible to create a textarea that blocks or removes http links from pasted or typed text dynamically.

Also, is it possible to only remove http links which aren't defined in a bracket. E.g.  Keep pasted or typed into textarea `(http://www.google.com)` and if the link was typed or pasted into the textarea as the following, remove `http://www.google.com` which is not in a bracket?

Futhermore, when the link is pasted or typed into the textarea it also needs to remove urls such as `https://www.google.com.au/search?` where the link continues after the domain url.

I have also created a
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/1/)

If an updated fiddle could be provided, it would be extremely helpful, as I am new to coding in html and jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: With reg ex, however, i am an absolute beginner at regEx, somebody else will have to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace with regex:

```
$("#txtarea").keyup(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*)/, ' ');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/3/)

---

Updated example for keep link with brackets regex `(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:[\w]+\.)(?:\.?[\w]{2,})+$`

```
$("#txtarea").keyup(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = this.value.replace(/(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:[\w]+\.)(?:\.?[\w]{2,})+$/, ' ');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/95b2msaj/5/)

Comment: However, the http link in the brackets is still being removed. Is it possible to keep the link in the brackets and remove the links that aren't in the bracket?

Comment: Updated answer added one more solution check it out.

Comment: This code is working well with domains such as google.com, however, doesn't seem to be removing links such as google.com.au/search? where there are still words continuing after the actual domain. Is it possible to apply the code to remove the entire link and keep it in the brackets?

Comment: @Dave ya i didn't consider this much of scenarios. You need to work on regex part for considering more.